# Why is the Spanish in the Canary Islands similar to Latin American Spanish?

Tags: diferencias-regionales

Why is the Spanish in the Canary Islands somewhat similar to Latin American Spanish?  I noticed this when I visited *Las Canarias*.  For example, I believe I heard *ustedes* instead of *vosotros*, which is what I heard on a visit to Barcelona.  (Both trips were about 20 years ago.)

Also, what are the main commonalities, and the main differences?

Comment: And to which of the hispanoamerican Spanish dialects are you comparing it to? Mexico? Colombia? Argentina? Each one is different.

Comment: @DGaleano - If I could give you a precise answer, I guess I'd be able to answer my own question, too!  The only thing I remember clearly is that there was no *vosotros*.  Vaguely, I remember understanding people better than in my visit to Barcelona, and I think someone told me, or I read somewhere, that in Canarias the language is not as different from New World Spanish as in Spain.

Comment: Not an answer, because it isn't sourced, but I remember the argument that Seville and Canarias where obvious ports to stop at for Spaniards going to the Americas. Recruitment of crews and the like was easier there, and there was a selection bias favoring their inhabitants to reach the New World

Comment: I'm sorry I seem to had bother you with my comment. I've never heard before that some of the Hispanoamérica dialects was similar to the canary islands. I was just curious to learn to which one.

Comment: @DGaleano - Let's hope someone can answer!  (We have  possible start with Rafael's comment.)

Comment: Relacionado: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26136/1674 y https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/3481/1674

Answer (score 6):

Diego Catalán  denomina a esta similitud "español atlántico" (contrapuesto al "español peninsular") en su obra [Génesis del español atlántico - Ondas varias a través de Océano](https://mdc.ulpgc.es/cdm/ref/collection/revhiscan/id/60) . Un extracto de la introducción:

> Las canarias son, vistas desde España, una pre-América, un mensaje del Nuevo Mundo hacia Euráfrica, y su lenguaje un anticipo del español americano, que nos permite iluminar desde un ángulo inédito la tradicional cuestión de las relaciones entre los dialectos de América y los de la España Atlántica.

El término es aceptado por unos y rechazado por otros. Pero como sea, en el texto se ofrece una explicación a las similitudes encontradas:

> ... La historia del español americano se inicia con el «periodo antillano» de la colonización (1493-1519), trentenio en que se forja la comunidad hispana de ultramar desde la cual se realizará después, en las dos décadas inmediatas (1520-1540), el asalto al continente. Allí en las Antillas, los colonos, desligados de su terruño, rotos los lazos que unían a cada cual con su particular comunidad, se amalgaman en una sociedad nueva que necesita crearse su propio lenguaje comunal.

Esta [página](http://www.tulane.edu/~howard/spanling/Dial/EspAtl.html) menciona que las Canarias fueron una escala muy importante en las expediciones de los conquistadores españoles y agrega:

> Un ejemplo es el caso de 'ceceo' sevillano que con los primeros colonizadores españoles viajó atravesando el Océano Atlántico hasta llegar a las Antillanas para más tarde pasar de la misma manera al continente y propagarse por todo el Nuevo Mundo.

y además:

> [...] Pues los primeros colonos, al hacer escala en las Canarias, también dejaron su constancia lingüística allí, esto es porqué en el español canario también existe el fenómeno de 'ceceo'

Comment: El periodo antillano nada tiene que ver con Las Canarias.

Answer (score 4):

En la mediateca de la página web del Gobierno de Canarias he encontrado el artículo ["El español hablado en Canarias"](http://www3.gobiernodecanarias.org/medusa/mediateca/publicaciones/?attachment_id=2599), de [Gonzalo Ortega Ojeda](http://www.academiacanarialengua.org/academicos/gortegaojeda/), catedrático del Departamento de Filología Española de la Universidad de La Laguna, que da la siguiente explicación:

> La modalidad lingüística hablada en el Archipiélago Canario se inscribe en el llamado español atlántico o meridional. Por tanto, nuestra variedad forma grupo común con el andaluz, especialmente con el occidental, y con el español de América. 
>   Las razones históricas que han determinado esto son conocidas: el castellano se implanta en Canarias a lo largo del siglo XV y primeros años del siglo XVI, una vez se consuman la conquista y colonización de dicho territorio por parte de la Corona de Castilla. De modo que ha sido la virtual identidad de los procesos de anexión lo que explica las muchas analogías que presenta el español de las Islas con el de Ultramar. Esas analogías, de forma más concreta, se deben a los siguientes hechos: 
>   
>   1º) La práctica coincidencia en las fechas de la conquista y colonización respectivas
>   
>   2º) La misma procedencia geográfica de los colonos de uno y otro lado del Atlántico
>   
>   3º) La relación secular y sostenida entre Canarias y América  –y el Caribe en particular–, en virtud del fenómeno de la emigración
>   
>   Los aspectos lingüísticos en los que se dejan sentir más claramente esas analogías son el fónico y el gramatical. El léxico, por su propia naturaleza, es el que representa un mayor distanciamiento, aunque tampoco son raras las similitudes. En todo caso, y antes de señalar, sacrificando 
>   inevitablemente algunas cosas, las peculiaridades isleñas de cada una de las vertientes del idioma, conviene aclarar que el español canario presenta una notable diversidad o polimorfismo, 
>   como corresponde a una región físicamente fragmentada y como corresponde también a unos condicionantes naturales y culturales no siempre homogéneos en el transcurso de su joven historia. Ésa es la razón por la que los especialistas, aun reconociendo una base de coincidencia incuestionable entre los distintos espacios insulares, prefieren la etiqueta de hablas canarias.

Comment: Exactamente, es mas andaluz que otra cosa.